# NSCoder encoding and decoding of c data type

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, encoding, type-conversion

I am making and app to transfer audio to the receiving server. I want to encode the audio buffer in order to stream. I made a class which stores this buffer and some other information. When I decode the data after encoding the main object, these two objects have different audio buffer.

So the conclusion is I am making a mistake in encoding/decoding. Here is my code for encoding the buffer

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeBytes:&_data length:sizeof(float *)];
    [aCoder encodeInt:_numFrames forKey:numFrames];
    [aCoder encodeInt:_numChannels forKey:numChannels];
}
```

NOTE `_data` has `(float *)` c data type

The decoding logic goes here

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        NSUInteger length = 0;
        {
            const uint8_t *buffer = [aDecoder decodeBytesForKey:data returnedLength:&length];
            assert(length);
            memcpy(&_data, buffer, length);
        }
        _numFrames = [aDecoder decodeInt32ForKey:numFrames];
        _numChannels = [aDecoder decodeInt32ForKey:numChannels];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I am using this method to compare if they are identical

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    AudioPacket *compareObject = (AudioPacket *)object;
    return (_data == compareObject.data && _numFrames == compareObject.numFrames && _numChannels == compareObject.numChannels);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but when you encode `_data` you don't give it a key:

```
[aCoder encodeBytes:&_data length:sizeof(float *)];
```

When you decode `_data` you use a key `data`:

```
 const uint8_t *buffer = [aDecoder decodeBytesForKey:data returnedLength:&length];
```

Perhaps you want a version of `encodeBytes` that also takes a key

```
 encodeBytes:length:forKey:
```